# Google Apps Script Service Using Too Much Computer Time for One Day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

So I got the error message in the subject on the 1 (one) script I had running yesterday and I am assuming I will get a similar message today.

I have improved the script (which has a trigger to run once per minute) so it functions more along the lines of how it is supposed to however the error message got me thinking as to what sort of functions or bits of programs might be asking for more service time than others.

For example, I have had to use multiple sleep calls in my google apps script to allow the data import to run and again for the worksheet changes/copy paste calls to process. Are all those sleep calls counting against me in terms of service time used?

I would ask on the community's behalf that this be left as an open ended question not specific to the sleep function. What sorts of parts of a script are demanding service time and which are not (if any).

Comment: I would assume the time limit is wallclock time, not CPU time -- so yes, the sleep calls are included.

Comment: Have the same sleep problem.  Google must not have the tech to measure actual CPU usage rather than time from start to finish. Frustrating limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to a service (Spreadsheet, Calendar or whatever) takes more time than regular JavaScript operations. 
For example, if you have to modify 10 cells in a Spreadsheet, 
calling range.setValue() 10 times takes far more time than having all the data in an array and then updating the spreadsheet in one go using range.setValues().

If you can paste pieces of your code, the community will be able to offer more advice on how to improve your script.

Comment: Thanks to both of your for answering. Definitely helped my understanding. I am down to 1 failure per day - which I can live with for now.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is on CPU time used in time based triggers, and I believe those sleep calls are counted against your limit. I'd encourage you to find ways to avoid the sleep calls, or schedule your script to run less often.

Comment: can you provide some functions ?