# Google Apps Script- trigger-driven time

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having a problem with the quotas for Google services, specifically those associated with the trigger -driven Time (clock)

I get the message `"Service using too much computer time for one day"`

I have 4 different reports, at different times everyday.

Example:

```
Report 1 : 9-10

Report 2: 11-12 

Report 3: 18-19 

Report 4: 20-21
```

Script execution is short about a minute , but for example if the report  1 is scheduled between 9-10, at times it runs from 9:58 - 9:59.

My question is if this happen, will the report and quotas would be exceeded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The exception message "`Service using too much computer time for one day`", indicates that the script exceeded the total allowable execution time for one day. It most commonly occurs for scripts that run on a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), which have a lower daily limit than scripts executed manually.

Apps Script services impose daily quotas and hard limitations on some features. If you exceed a quota or limitation, your script will throw an exception and terminate execution.

Quotas are set at different levels for users of consumer accounts, Google Apps for Your Domain, and Google Apps for Business, Education, or Government.

This is the [list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) of daily quotas as of April 2014. Daily quotas are also refreshed at the end of 24-hour window.

Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106464/google-apps-script-service-using-too-much-computer-time-for-one-day) for more information.