# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Service using too much computer time for one day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apologies, I see this question has been raised before on the forum, but the answer always seems to be "nothing wrong with your script", so is Google arbitrarily choosing scripts not to run?

Anyway, the following is my script, which is set on a trigger to run once per day - per my execution logs, its run-time is ~100 seconds a day when it doesn't fail. Essentially, its purpose is to take 12 cells of a HTML import and value paste it with a timestamp in another sheet.

If you could please let me know if there is an error with the script itself, that would be greatly appreciated!

```
function dailyLog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('HTML Import');
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('HTML Import Cleanup');
  var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
  logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1,12,1).setValue(new Date());  // insert 
timestamp
  var range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Thank you,

Liam

EDIT: here's a screenshot of my executions
[image]

EDIT 2: here's a screenshot of my executions with filters cleared

[image: filters cleared]

Comment: View>Executions>uncheck "ran as me": What do you see for yesterday? What's the total time taken? Post screenshot.

Comment: @I'-'I thank you for your response - I have edited my original post to include this

Comment: Clear all filters in the execution log

Comment: @I'-'I ok, i think i have captured what you requested - thank you again!

Comment: So What's the total run time/day? Seems like it'll easily cross the  quota of 90min/day. Solved?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: @I'-'I the sum is >90 minutes, yes, so I guess that limit applies to not just scripts, but also any addons you have running?

Comment: Addons are just published scripts. Except for manually-run scripts( from the script editor), All triggers run time counts.

Comment: @I'-'I ok thank you so much - solved

Comment: Welcome. Many members of this community don't like that it be called "a forum". Posts should be straight to the point, in other words, avoid greetings, "thank", signatures, and other social conventions commonly used on forums. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script Service Using Too Much Computer Time for One Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106464/google-apps-script-service-using-too-much-computer-time-for-one-day)